# ActiveAdmin set tab active

Tags: tabs, activeadmin

I use 'tabs' for my resource in ActiveAdmin page.
Something like this:

```
tabs do
  tab 'General' do
  end
  tab 'Content' do
  end
end
```

Have AA ability for set not first tab as active?
Something like:

```
tab 'Content', active: true
```

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out that ActiveAdmin doesn't support this out of the box:
JS code for tabs otherwise can set active tab accordingly css class `ui-tabs-active` but has not ability for passes css class to html.
I've prepared push-request for adding this ability:

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/5411'

This allows make next:

```
tab 'Content', {class: 'ui-tabs-active'} do
  #omitted code
end
```

and tab `content` will be active when page loading.

Comment: This is not working for me. I also tried `tab 'Content', html_options: { class: 'ui-tabs-active ui-state-active' }` with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it is not in last gem version but in master branch.